# IEDriverServer fails with Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2.41 with the IEDriverServer 32 bits

IE 9.0.8112

Win 7

Selenium runs IE, opens the page, but when tries to select a drop down item it fails

**IEDriverServer** log fragment:

```
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:559 Script.cpp(40) Entering Script::Initialize
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:559 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\commandhandlers\ExecuteScriptCommandHandler.h(85) Entering ExecuteScriptCommandHandler::PopulateArgumentArray
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:559 Script.cpp(160) Entering Script::Execute
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:559 Script.cpp(468) Entering Script::**CreateAnonymousFunction**
D 2014-04-04 18:06:38:710 Script.cpp(240) -2147352319 [Unknown error 0x80020101]: Failed to execute anonymous function, no exception information retrieved
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:711 response.cc(68) Entering Response::SetErrorResponse
W 2014-04-04 18:06:38:711 response.cc(69) Error response has status code 17 and message 'JavaScript error' message
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:712 IECommandExecutor.cpp(569) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetCurrentBrowser
T 2014-04-04 18:06:38:712 IECommandExecutor.cpp(575) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetManagedBrowser
```

The test with IE was working ok but I started to have this problem. I was using Selenium 2.40, tried to update Selenium to see if that fix the problem, but no.

The test run correctly with other browsers.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

Test code fragment

```
        selenium.open("/NET/user.faces");

        assertEquals(".Page title.", selenium.getTitle());

        // utility method that takes an screenshot
        takeScreenshot("home");

        selenium.waitForCondition(
                "selenium.isElementPresent('id=subViewPrincipal:viewFragmentPrincipal:formUsuarioCliente:comboTiposDocumento')",
                "5000");

      // Fails here
        selenium.select(
                "id=subViewPrincipal:viewFragmentPrincipal:formUsuarioCliente:comboTiposDocumento",
                "label=CUIL");
```

HTML fragment:

```
<TD class=label_formulario>Tipo de documento *</TD>
<TD class=value_formulario>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/JavaScript src="/NET/.ibmjsfres/hxclient_core_v3_1_14.js"></SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/JavaScript   src="/NET/.ibmjsfres/hxclient_S_v3_1_14_es.js?viewLocale=es"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/JavaScript>
  if (hX_6) hX_6.setResourceServer("/NET/.ibmjsfres");
  if(hX_6 && hX_6.setLocale) hX_6.setLocale("es");
</SCRIPT>
<SELECT id=subViewPrincipal:viewFragmentPrincipal:formUsuarioCliente:comboTiposDocumento class=selectOneMenu size=1 name=subViewPrincipal:viewFragmentPrincipal:formUsuarioCliente:comboTiposDocumento> 
    <OPTION value=1>CUIT</OPTION> 
    <OPTION selected value=2>CUIL</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</TD>
```

The log shows that it fails when tries to inject an anonymous function, this is an extended fragment of a new execution:

```
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:248 server.cc(359) Entering Server::SendResponseToClient
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:248 response.cc(32) Entering Response::Deserialize
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:248 server.cc(413) Entering Server::SendHttpOk
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(62) Entering Server::OnHttpEvent
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(128) Entering Server::ProcessRequest
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(196) Entering Server::ReadRequestBody
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(137) Process request with: URI: /session/28cf18c5-d328-4390-b103-6caca8dc11e3/execute HTTP verb: POST
body: {"args":[],"script":"if (window.localStorage) {   window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify([]));   window.alert = function(msg) {     var alerts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverAlerts'));     alerts.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify(alerts));   };   window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverConfirms', JSON.stringify([]));   if (!('__webdriverNextConfirm' in window.localStorage)) {     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverNextConfirm', JSON.stringify(true));   }   window.confirm = function(msg) {     var confirms = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverConfirms'));     confirms.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverConfirms', JSON.stringify(confirms));     var res = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverNextConfirm'));     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverNextConfirm', JSON.stringify(true));     return res;   }; } else {   if (window.__webdriverAlerts) { return; }   window.__webdriverAlerts = [];   window.alert = function(msg) { window.__webdriverAlerts.push(msg); };   window.__webdriverConfirms = [];   window.__webdriverNextConfirm = true;   window.confirm = function(msg) {     window.__webdriverConfirms.push(msg);     var res = window.__webdriverNextConfirm;     window.__webdriverNextConfirm = true;     return res;   }; }"}
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(230) Entering Server::DispatchCommand
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(530) Entering Server::LookupCommand
D 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(239) Command: POST /session/28cf18c5-d328-4390-b103-6caca8dc11e3/execute {"args":[],"script":"if (window.localStorage) {   window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify([]));   window.alert = function(msg) {     var alerts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverAlerts'));     alerts.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify(alerts));   };   window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverConfirms', JSON.stringify([]));   if (!('__webdriverNextConfirm' in window.localStorage)) {     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverNextConfirm', JSON.stringify(true));   }   window.confirm = function(msg) {     var confirms = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverConfirms'));     confirms.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverConfirms', JSON.stringify(confirms));     var res = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverNextConfirm'));     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverNextConfirm', JSON.stringify(true));     return res;   }; } else {   if (window.__webdriverAlerts) { return; }   window.__webdriverAlerts = [];   window.alert = function(msg) { window.__webdriverAlerts.push(msg); };   window.__webdriverConfirms = [];   window.__webdriverNextConfirm = true;   window.confirm = function(msg) {     window.__webdriverConfirms.push(msg);     var res = window.__webdriverNextConfirm;     window.__webdriverNextConfirm = true;     return res;   }; }"}
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 server.cc(346) Entering Server::LookupSession
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:252 IESession.cpp(187) Entering IESession::ExecuteCommand
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(151) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnSetCommand
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 command.cc(27) Entering Command::Populate
D 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 command.cc(33) Raw JSON command: { "command" : "executeScript", "locator" : { "sessionid" : "28cf18c5-d328-4390-b103-6caca8dc11e3" }, "parameters" : {"args":[],"script":"if (window.localStorage) {   window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify([]));   window.alert = function(msg) {     var alerts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverAlerts'));     alerts.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverAlerts', JSON.stringify(alerts));   };   window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverConfirms', JSON.stringify([]));   if (!('__webdriverNextConfirm' in window.localStorage)) {     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverNextConfirm', JSON.stringify(true));   }   window.confirm = function(msg) {     var confirms = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverConfirms'));     confirms.push(msg);     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverConfirms', JSON.stringify(confirms));     var res = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('__webdriverNextConfirm'));     window.localStorage.setItem('__webdriverNextConfirm', JSON.stringify(true));     return res;   }; } else {   if (window.__webdriverAlerts) { return; }   window.__webdriverAlerts = [];   window.alert = function(msg) { window.__webdriverAlerts.push(msg); };   window.__webdriverConfirms = [];   window.__webdriverNextConfirm = true;   window.confirm = function(msg) {     window.__webdriverConfirms.push(msg);     var res = window.__webdriverNextConfirm;     window.__webdriverNextConfirm = true;     return res;   }; }"} }
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(162) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnExecCommand
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(453) Entering IECommandExecutor::DispatchCommand
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(569) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetCurrentBrowser
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(575) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetManagedBrowser
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(525) Entering IECommandExecutor::IsAlertActive
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 Browser.cpp(631) Entering Browser::GetActiveDialogWindowHandle
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 Browser.cpp(175) Entering Browser::GetWindowHandle
D 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(539) No alert handle is found
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(569) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetCurrentBrowser
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IECommandExecutor.cpp(575) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetManagedBrowser
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 Browser.cpp(95) Entering Browser::GetDocument
I 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 Browser.cpp(99) No child frame focus. Focus is on top-level frame
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:253 IESession.cpp(208) Beginning wait for response length to be not zero
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:261 Browser.cpp(557) Entering Browser::GetDocumentFromWindow
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:266 Script.cpp(40) Entering Script::Initialize
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:266 c:\projects\webdriver\cpp\iedriver\commandhandlers\ExecuteScriptCommandHandler.h(85) Entering ExecuteScriptCommandHandler::PopulateArgumentArray
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:266 Script.cpp(160) Entering Script::Execute
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:266 Script.cpp(468) Entering Script::**CreateAnonymousFunction**
D 2014-04-07 12:48:30:357 Script.cpp(240) -2147352319 [**Unknown error 0x80020101**]: Failed to execute anonymous function, no exception information retrieved
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:363 response.cc(68) Entering Response::SetErrorResponse
W 2014-04-07 12:48:30:363 response.cc(69) **Error response has status code 17 and message 'JavaScript error' message**
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:363 IECommandExecutor.cpp(569) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetCurrentBrowser
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:363 IECommandExecutor.cpp(575) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetManagedBrowser
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:363 response.cc(43) Entering Response::Serialize
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 IESession.cpp(217) Found non-zero response length
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 IECommandExecutor.cpp(185) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnGetResponse
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 IECommandExecutor.cpp(290) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnIsSessionValid
D 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 server.cc(308) Response: {"sessionId":"28cf18c5-d328-4390-b103-6caca8dc11e3","status":17,"value":{"message":"JavaScript error"}}

T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 server.cc(359) Entering Server::SendResponseToClient
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 response.cc(32) Entering Response::Deserialize
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:373 server.cc(451) Entering Server::SendHttpInternalError
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:395 server.cc(62) Entering Server::OnHttpEvent
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:395 server.cc(128) Entering Server::ProcessRequest
T 2014-04-07 12:48:30:395 server.cc(137) Process request with: URI: /session/28cf18c5-d328-4390-b103-6caca8dc11e3 HTTP verb: DELETE
body: {}
```

Comment: Well what code is failing?

Comment: @Jonathan - If you could please post your code and the DOM snippit you are working against that would be helpful.  Out of curiosity if you roll back your selenium version and driver does it start working again?

Comment: Edited the question, added info.
@ Arran IEDriverServer logs the error, maybe comes from IE.
@DanSnell The problem started with the previous version, I didn't rollback.

Comment: So one more question.  If you run this manually in IE are there any errors being thrown?

Comment: @DanSnell I can't reproduce the error manually. Neither javascript console shows any problem.